# AngularJS/Karma - Testing function returns promise that has been resolved or rejected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

Trying to unit test in Karma with AngularMock if my function has returned a promise that was rejected but can't seem to find ANYTHING surprisingly on the matter.

I have a service like UserService, which has a function: `processIdentityResponse` which returns a promise that is either resolved or rejected depending on the logic inside:

```
processIdentityResponse: function(response)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (response.data.banned) {
        deferred.reject(response);
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }   
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I want to test that if the banned property exists then a rejected promise is returned and if not, that it is resolved... how can I achieve this?

I tried something like the following to no success:

```
it('should return a rejected promise if status is a string', function() {
    var rejected = false;
    UserService.processIdentityResponse(data).catch(function() {
        rejected = true;
    });
    expect(rejected).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems like the reason is because the promise wasn't yet resolved as it's asynchronous functionality.

You basically have to `$rootScope.$digest()` afterwards like so:

```
it('should return a rejected promise if status is a string', inject(function($rootScope) {
    var rejected = false;
    UserService.processIdentityResponse(data).catch(function() {
        rejected = true;
    });
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(rejected).toBe(true);
}));
```

Comment: I find it quite bizarre to use scope on a service. It seems reserved for directives & controllers.

Comment: @trysis how would you otherwise test promises? I'd love to see the way without calling `$rootScope.$digest()`

Comment: I was not disputing the usefulness or the necessity, just stating that it seems weird. Services are supposed to be completely isolated from DOM logic, and `$scope`/`$rootScope` are pretty tied to the DOM, though some of their methods, like `$digest`, do not need to be.

Comment: instead of using the _rejected_ variable, is easier to define a spy and check that it has been called: `var spy = jasmine.createSpy(); yourFunc.catch(spy); expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: @dmitry-frank it is used to fire a digest cycle which angular needs to process the promise, without it rejected would never be set to true. You are right that it is reserved for directives/controllers but this is a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Dominic said, I used [Jasimine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) `done()` Asynchronous Support function. Think of it as a pause/waiting function.

```
describe('my description',function(){
 beforeEach(function(done){
  var rejected = true;
  var promise = UserService.processIdentityResponse(data);//add ur service or function that will return a promise here
  setTimeout(function(){done();},1500);//set time to 1500ms or more if it's a long request
 });

 it('it should be true',function(done){
  promise.catch(function(){ rejected=true});
  $rootScope.$digest();//important
  expect(rejected).toBeTruthy();
  done();
 });
});
```